# Azure custom domain causes static files to stop being served

Tags: python, azure, static, bottle

Using Visual Studio 2013, I created a Bottle Python website, uploaded it to Azure, all works nicely using their assigned ."azurewebsites.net" url.

Then added custom domain, and now static files are not being served (eg.css)

Any idea what the problem is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer (compliments to Alex Strickland) in this question:
[Django on Azure not loading static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799294/django-on-azure-not-loading-static-files)

The solution was to simply switch OFF Python in the Azure Settings for this web site! No idea why this works, but it does!